# StackExchange.Redis sync-ops and conn-sec

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Every now and then we received a large set of timeouts (around peak time for website traffic) with lots of logs in the following form:

```
Timeout performing GET (5000ms)
next: GET ObjectPageView.120.633.0
inst: 21
qu: 0
qs: 0
aw: False
bw: SpinningDown
rs: ReadAsync
ws: Idle
in: 0
last-in: 0
cur-in: 0
sync-ops: 456703
async-ops: 1
conn-sec: 72340.11
mc: 1/1/0
mgr: 10 of 10 available
IOCP: (Busy=0 Free=1800 Min=600 Max=1800)
WORKER: (Busy=720 Free=1080 Min=600 Max=1800)
v: 2.6.90.64945
```

What do `sync-ops` and `conn-sec` stand for?  The rest of the numbers seem fine, but these seem high and I'm not entirely sure what they are describing.

Comment: As mentioned in this [PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/pull/2300), these are "A count of synchronous operation calls", and "How long the bridge in question has been connected". I guess you could get more help by opening an issue over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are statistic about the current connection:

- ["sync-ops"](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs#L1948) a count of synchronous operations (as opposed to async-ops for asynchronous operations) performed on the current connection.
- ["conn-sec"](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/StackExchange.Redis/ExceptionFactory.cs#L335) is the current duration of the current connection (from connected until now)